# Spring data Mongodb Group by with multi criteria - issues

Tags: spring-data-mongodb

I want to group by particular column whose count is equal to some input number.

**my query**:

```
Criteria countCriteria = Criteria.where("count").is(2);

if(!criteria.getCriteriaObject().keySet().isEmpty()){
    countCriteria.andOperator(criteria);
}
```

**criteria**: Criteria Object what I get as input

```
Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(
    Aggregation.group(MBR_REWARD_ENROLL_NUM).count().as("count"),
    Aggregation.match(countCriteria)
);
```

If I pass some Criteria to 'criteria' object, it is not working. If I don't pass anything, then it is working. Could somebody help me?

Comment: Could I know whether anybody have suggestions for this issue?

Comment: How can I get list of records group by column "xxxx" with count as per input number? I know my above query  has some problem. Could somebody help me?

Comment: How to add extra criteria for the below groupBy operation: Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(
    Aggregation.group(MBR_REWARD_ENROLL_NUM).count().as("count"),
    Aggregation.match(Criteria.where("count").is(2))
);. Can somebody look into this?